# How do I format a query to pull out all records where the date = max date of the records?

Tags: apex, soql, query, max

I have an object that stores performance data for another object (eg Account). The performance data is loaded at various times (ie can be monthly, quarterly, annually) so there will be multiple instances of Performance for each Account.

I need a query to extract only the latest records for all Accounts, so something like this (which I know isn't possible in SOQL):

Select fieldA, fieldB from Performance where Month = (select max(Month) from Peformance)

How do I go about this in one query? I know I can query the max(Month) first and then use the result in the where clause, but can I do it all in one?

Comment: why not `Order By Month Desc` and take the first record?

Comment: I need the latest Performance record for each Account, not just one record. There will be multiple records with the same Month, one per Account.

Comment: do you care only about the current (e.g. November 2019) month for each account or the most recent month _even if in the past_ for each Account? (e.g. Account A's last Performance was in July 2019 but Account B's last performance was in November 2019)

Comment: The most recent one - all Accounts will have a record for the same Month. So all will have a record for (if annually) March 2017, March 2018, then March 2019. So when I run the query I want to pick up all for March 2019 only.

Comment: I don't think this is possible to extract in a single SOQL query. You are interested in getting the performance record detail/s where Month matches the MAX value for all the performance records... Grouping or Nested queries will not help in this case.